# How to prevent a UITableViewCell from losing its selection state on section refresh?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, swift4.2

I have a UITableViewCell that is selected, but when I call this code:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)    
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

It loses its selection state, but even if I do these two things:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)
tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)    
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// get cell
cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
```

The cell loses its selection state for a second, which is glitchy. I would like the cell's look to appear unchanged even as a blink.

Note: I put log statements at the usual shouldHighlight and didUnSelect etc methods, but didn't get a hit on those guys.

Comment: why do you use `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`? those are needed only when you do several manipulations with the `tableView` which should be *animated* together..

Comment: I've added the answer then..

Answer (score 1):

Do not enclose the lines of code in `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`. This starts an "animation transaction" to animate the `tableView` manipulations together. I assume the `tableView` in this case runs an animation even when you set `.none` as an animation, thus ending in the glitch.